KMDF USB Driver: WDF SetConfiguration API doesn’t work for IAP2 interface descriptors
I have a USB drive which advertises vendor specific IAP2 descriptors(See Table 1). With inhouse developed driver, I want to set IAP2 Interface by invoking SetConfiguration request. When I set the configuration for IAP2 interface, the driver gets reloaded and the device advertises new capabilies which has only BOT mode interfaces(See Table 2). Note: At any point of time the drive either advertises IAP2 descritpors or MSC descriptors only.
Table 1: //Only Vendor specific - IAP descriptors
Device Descriptor
    Configuration Descriptor
        IAP2 Interface Descritpr 0, AlternateSetting 0 (IAP2 Authentication interface - Has 2 EPs)
        IAP2 Interface Descritpr 1, AlternateSetting 0 (IAP2 EA interface - Has 0 Eps)
        IAP2 Interface Descritpr 1, AlternateSetting 1 (IAP2 EA interface - Has 2 Eps)

Table 2: //Only MSC - BOT mode descritpors
Device Descriptor
    Configuration Descriptor
        Interface Descritpr 0, AlternateSetting 0 (MSC for BOT mode - Has 2 EPs)

I have compiled below observations for the code changes to invoke SetConfiguration request.
Observation 1:
    WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS configParams;
    WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS_INIT_MULTIPLE_INTERFACES(&configParams, 0, NULL);
    status = WdfUsbTargetDeviceSelectConfig(pDeviceContext->UsbDevice, NULL, &configParams);

On invoking SetConfiguration with above settings, I notice back to back SetConfiguration Request and then SetInterface request. SetInterface packet contains request for IAP2 Interface=1, AlternateSetting=0. Both requests(SetConfiguration and SetInterface) are successful and the traces are captured in wireshark/lecory. However, immediately underlying USB stack seems to trigger a warm reset and the driver gets reloaded. Lecroy traces shows that the SetFeature was invoked for U1/U2 enable but Wireshark trace doesn't capture warm reset requests. Now, the device advertizes new capabilities which has MSC BOT mode configuration. SetConfiguration invocation for BOT mode is successful(See Table 2).
Observation 2:
    WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS configParams;
    UCHAR numInterfaces = WdfUsbTargetDeviceGetNumInterfaces(pDeviceContext->UsbDevice); //Returns value=2
    PWDF_USB_INTERFACE_SETTING_PAIR settingPairs = ExAllocatePool2(
        POOL_FLAG_PAGED,
        sizeof(WDF_USB_INTERFACE_SETTING_PAIR) * numInterfaces,
        PnpPoolTag
    );

    pDeviceContext->UsbInterface = WdfUsbTargetDeviceGetInterface(pDeviceContext->UsbDevice, 0); //Retrieve interface=0
    BYTE NumOfSettings = WdfUsbInterfaceGetNumSettings(pDeviceContext->UsbInterface); //Returns value=1
    WdfUsbInterfaceGetDescriptor(pDeviceContext->UsbInterface, 0, &pDeviceContext->InterfaceDescriptor); //Retrieve descriptor for interface=0, AltSetting=0
            
    settingPairs[0].UsbInterface = pDeviceContext->UsbInterface;
    settingPairs[0].SettingIndex = 0;

    pDeviceContext->UsbInterface = WdfUsbTargetDeviceGetInterface(pDeviceContext->UsbDevice, 1); //Retrieve interface=1
    NumOfSettings = WdfUsbInterfaceGetNumSettings(pDeviceContext->UsbInterface); //Returns value=2
    WdfUsbInterfaceGetDescriptor(pDeviceContext->UsbInterface, 1, &pDeviceContext->InterfaceDescriptor); //Retrieve descriptor for interface=1, AltSetting=1
  
    settingPairs[1].UsbInterface = pDeviceContext->UsbInterface;
    settingPairs[1].SettingIndex = 1;       

    WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS_INIT_MULTIPLE_INTERFACES(&configParams, numInterfaces, settingPairs);
    status = WdfUsbTargetDeviceSelectConfig(pDeviceContext->UsbDevice, NULL, &configParams);

On invoking SetConfiguration with above settings, I notice back to back SetConfiguration Request and then SetInterface request. SetInterface packet contains request for IAP2 Interface=1, AlternateSetting=1. Both requests(SetConfiguration and SetInterface) requests are successful and the traces are captured in wireshark/lecory. However, immediately underlying USB stack seems to trigger a warm reset and the driver gets reloaded. Lecroy traces shows that the SetFeature was invoked for U1/U2 enable but Wireshark trace doesn't capture warm reset requests. Now, the device advertizes new capabilities which has MSC BOT mode configuration. SetConfiguration invocation for BOT mode is successful(See Table 2).
Observation 3:
    WDF_USB_CONTROL_SETUP_PACKET wdfusbcontrolsetupacket;
    WDF_USB_BMREQUEST_RECIPIENT bmRequestRecepient = BmRequestToDevice;
    WDF_USB_BMREQUEST_DIRECTION bmRequestDirection = BMREQUEST_HOST_TO_DEVICE;
    ULONG bytestransfered;
    WDF_USB_CONTROL_SETUP_PACKET_INIT(&wdfusbcontrolsetupacket, bmRequestDirection, bmRequestRecepient, 0x09, 1, 0);
    status = WdfUsbTargetDeviceSendControlTransferSynchronously(
        pDeviceContext->UsbDevice,
        WDF_NO_HANDLE,
        NULL,
        &wdfusbcontrolsetupacket,
        NULL,
        &bytestransfered
    );
    

On invoking SetConfiguration with above settings, I notice only SetConfiguration Request provided there is no breakpoint added in windbg. The invocation is successful and the traces are captured in wireshark/lecory. However, immediately underlying USB stack seems to trigger a warm reset and the driver gets reloaded. Both lecroy and Wireshark trace doesn't capture warm reset SetFeature requests. Now, the device advertizes new capabilities which has MSC BOT mode configuration. SetConfiguration invocation for BOT mode is successful(See Table 2).
Observation 4:
    WDF_USB_CONTROL_SETUP_PACKET wdfusbcontrolsetupacket;
    WDF_USB_BMREQUEST_RECIPIENT bmRequestRecepient = BmRequestToDevice;
    WDF_USB_BMREQUEST_DIRECTION bmRequestDirection = BMREQUEST_HOST_TO_DEVICE;
    ULONG bytestransfered;
    WDF_USB_CONTROL_SETUP_PACKET_INIT(&wdfusbcontrolsetupacket, bmRequestDirection, bmRequestRecepient, 0x09, 1, 0);
    status = WdfUsbTargetDeviceSendControlTransferSynchronously(
        pDeviceContext->UsbDevice,
        WDF_NO_HANDLE,
        NULL,
        &wdfusbcontrolsetupacket,
        NULL,
        &bytestransfered
    );

On invoking SetConfiguration with above settings, if I add debug breakpoint in windbg just before I invoke WdfUsbTargetDeviceSendControlTransferSynchronously then on some instances WdfUsbTargetDeviceSendControlTransferSynchronously will fail with Status = 0xc000000e(IRP USBD_STATUS: USBD_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER (0x80000300)) or status = 0xc0000001(USBD_STATUS_XACT_ERROR (0xc0000011)). Lecroy doesn't capture the SetConfiguration packet for IAP2 descriptor, however wireshark captures it. Driver gets reloaded and the device advertises BOT capabilities. SetConfiguration is successful for BOT mode(See Table 2).
Observation 5:
    WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS_INIT_SINGLE_INTERFACE(&configParams);
    status = WdfUsbTargetDeviceSelectConfig(pDeviceContext->UsbDevice, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &configParams);

On invoking SetConfiguration with above settings, WdfUsbTargetDeviceSelectConfig request fails. Both wireshark and lecory doesn't capture traces for SetConfiguration.
Can someone please help in giving any clues for below questions.

Any possible reasons for WarmReset getting triggered by some underlying USB stack layer and why I am unable to set IAP2 configuration via SetConfiguration request persistently.
Why WdfUsbTargetDeviceSendControlTransferSynchronously returns Status = 0xc000000e(IRP USBD_STATUS: USBD_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER (0x80000300)) or status = 0xc0000001(USBD_STATUS_XACT_ERROR (0xc0000011)) on adding a debug breakpoints in windbg.
Why SetConfiguration with WDF_USB_DEVICE_SELECT_CONFIG_PARAMS_INIT_SINGLE_INTERFACE doesn't work

